# Python Struct module behaves strange

Tags: python

I'm using the struct module, and things aren't going as I expected. Its due to some misunderstanding I have with the module I'm sure.

```
import struct
s = struct.Struct('Q');
print s.size
s = struct.Struct('H L Q');
print s.size
s = struct.Struct('H I Q');
print s.size
s = struct.Struct('H I Q H');
print s.size
```

The output of this is:

```
8
24
16
18
```

What am I missing here? Why are the second and third different sizes, and why is the fourth 
not 16?

Comment: You're using native formats, which means sizes and padding are dependent on your platform. If you want to use standard sizes with no padding, prepend the format string with `=`, `<`, `>` or `!`.

Comment: Yep alignment. Why oh why did I assume that python would behave the same as my packed struct? Thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alignment issue.

Assuming you're running on a 64-bit non-Windows platform: Q and L will be 8-byte long, I is 4-byte, and H is 2-byte.

And these types must be put on a location which is a multiple of its size for best efficiency.

Therefore, the 2nd struct would be arranged as:

```
HH______ LLLLLLLL QQQQQQQQ
```

the 3rd struct:

```
HH__IIII QQQQQQQQ
```

and the 4th struct:

```
HH__IIII QQQQQQQQ HH
```

---

If you don't want alignment, and require L to have 4 byte (the "standard" size), you'll need to use the `=` or `>` or `<` format, as described in http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct-alignment:

```
import struct
s = struct.Struct('=Q')
print s.size
s = struct.Struct('=HLQ')
print s.size
s = struct.Struct('=HIQ')
print s.size
s = struct.Struct('=HIQH')
print s.size
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/EMlgm

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [the documentation of struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

> Alternatively, the first character of the format string can be used to indicate the byte order, size and alignment of the packed data, according to the following table:

```
Character Byte order             Size       Alignment
@         native                 native     native
=         native                 standard   none
<         little-endian          standard   none
>         big-endian             standard   none
!         network (= big-endian) standard   none
```

> If the first character is not one of these, '@' is assumed.

Since you didn't give any size hint, `native` size and alignment is chosen which can give unpredictable sizes thanks to alignment and different sizes. This should fix the issue:

```
import struct
print(struct.calcsize('!Q'))
print(struct.calcsize('!H L Q'))
print(struct.calcsize('!H I Q'))
print(struct.calcsize('!H I Q H'))
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm unpacking a packed C struct. In this case I would want to use < rather than ! correct?

Comment: @mdogg: No, in that case `=` would be correct, unless you unpack something you know for certain that it is little-endian, in that case use `<`.

Comment: @mdogg: Whether to use < or > depends on the endian-ness -- which means byte-order -- of the data in the packed C struct you're unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 64 bits architecture, then `int` is 4 bytes, and `long` is 8 bytes:

```
>>> struct.Struct('I').size
4
>>> struct.Struct('L').size
8
```

For the last one, this is what we call "alignment": http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct-alignment:

```
>>> struct.Struct('I').size
4
>>> struct.Struct('H').size
2
>>> struct.Struct('HI').size
8
# => aligned to the next word.
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with alignment.  If you add one of the byte order characters to the format, you will get the answers you expect.

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html